# Reading pList through NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, plist, nsuserdefaults

If i have values saved in pList Files. Now can i retrieve them using
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Field_Name"]

Taimur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NSUserDefaults` are not the same as your `plist` files. I am assuming that you are trying to use default settings in your app? Here is what you do

1. On first launch, read all the values from the plist. You can see this by looking for a flag in `NSUserDefaults` (see step 3)
2. Write default values to `NSUserDefaults`.
3. Set a flag in `NSUserDefaults` that the app has been opened.